# $a+b+c = 3$, prove that :$a\sqrt{a+3}+b\sqrt{b+3}+c\sqrt{c+3} \geq 6$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality, jensen-inequality, tangent-line-method

$a, b,c $ are positive real numbers such that $a+b+c = 3$, prove that :$a\sqrt{a+3}+b\sqrt{b+3}+c\sqrt{c+3} \geq 6$

Any ideas ?

Comment: *Any Ideas* from your side?

Comment: I tried $AM-GM$ but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: An ugly idea would be to replace $c$ with $3-a-b$, show (using derivatives) that the resulting two variable function is growing with respect to each variable and finding the global minimum of it being 6.

Comment: Try to use symmetry properties. Equality achieved for $(1,1,1)$.

Answer (score 4):

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2\sqrt{a^2+3}\geq6$$
for non-negatives $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$.

Indeed, by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2\sqrt{a^2+3}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}a^2\sqrt{(1+3)
(a^2+3)}\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}a^2(a+3)=\frac{1}{2}(a^3+b^3+c^3)+\frac{9}{2}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$a^3+b^3+c^3\geq3,$$
which is Power-Means:
$$\left(\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}\right)^2\geq\left(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}\right)^3.$$

Done!

Comment: Power means uses Jensen's inequality in its proof :)

Answer (score 2):

That's Jensen's inequality for the convex function $x\,\sqrt{x+3}=(x+3)^{3/2}-3\,\sqrt{x+3}$.

Answer (score 1):

By Holder
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{a+3}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+3}\geq(a+b+c)^3=27.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+3}\leq\frac{3}{4}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{a}{a+3}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1-a}{a+3}\geq0$$ or

$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1-a}{a+3}+\frac{1}{4}(a-1)\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-1)^2}{a+3}\geq0.$$
Done!